# What's the difference between Electromagnetic lens and an Electrostatic lens?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, lenses

So I've read a couple of pages and watches a few videos but at their core neither has answered this basic question.

I remember from the lecture that the prof. said that one needs a high current while the other needs a high voltage (with low current).

But I don't remember which is which and also I'd like to learn more about the commonalities and differences of applied electrostatics vs electromagnetism.

Comment: If no current is flowing there is no magnetic field to form a lens.

Comment: Ok sorry, one requires ALOT of current while the other requires only a little current but alot of voltage. That's how the prof. said it, I think.

Comment: Indeed, an electrostatic lens really should not need much current - the field should be _static_ and current from the power supply only needs to account for leakage or some of the beam hitting the lens elements.

Comment: I see, I'd love to learn more about this, because to be honest I understand very little of your statment.
What is a static field vs. dynamic (?) field?
I know that static electric charges are generating an electric field around them. But how are the charges static if there is any voltage that causes them to move?

What is leakage?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leakage_(electronics)

Comment: Ok I see, but the article makes it sounds as if leakage were something we don't want or rather a by product.

So summing up: In an electrostatic lens all our charges are not moving which causes an electrostatic field. (This would imply little to no voltage, correct?)

Now the only movement of charges happens through leaked current which is something we don't want. 

Correct?